# Hide tabs in Report View on Power BI website?

Tags: report, hide, powerbi

Is it possible to hide tabs from others in the report view on the power BI website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for hiding the pages will be out very soon.

Comment: @Josh Caplan - MSFT did this ever happen?

Comment: Yes. Check out the JavaScript API for embedding.

Comment: @JoshCaplan-MSFT I see API only for hiding all tab panel. Is it possible to hide one page only? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232586/hide-page-in-page-bar-in-power-bi-embedded )

Answer (score 1):

**There is currently no way to hide specific tabs.**

I would recommend that you create multiple reports and set those permissions accordingly.

Also, you can hide all of the information on a particular tab by using [row-level security](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-admin-rls/) with [page-level filters](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-how-to-use-a-report-filter/). For this, you'll need to be using an Enterprise Gateway connection.

The tab itself will still be visible, though.