# Hide page in page bar in Power BI embedded

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I'm embedding Power BI report into our application. I want to show / hide available pages of report based on state of our application. Is there any Javascript API to hide concrete page?

I known, that it is possible to hide page in Power BI desktop, but I need it modify dynamically for concrete user session.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently supported. At least I don't see in [page.ts source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/blob/165a584a80ac39efa83c423856fb7f7d9f3d7909/src/page.ts) a way to do this.

In [Microsoft official demo](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/pagenavigation.html) they [hided the navigation bar](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details) and used buttons in the web page to [change the active report page](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Page-Navigation), so you can use this workaround too.

> Page navigation is enabled/visible by default but can be disabled/hidden by adding the attribute on the element or specifying the setting in the embed configuration:

So to hide page navigation panel add attribute like this:

```
<div ... powerbi-settings-nav-content-pane-enabled="false"></div>
```

Or specify it in the embedded configuration details:

```
var embedConfig = {
    ...
    settings: {
        navContentPaneEnabled: false
    }
};
```

To switch the report to some page, call it's `setActive` method:

```
const page = report.page('ReportSection1');
page.setActive();
```

Comment: Andrey, thank you for your response. Yes, this is the way, but unfortunately not very elegant.